# Making property [NonSerialized] for a value

Tags: c#, json-serialization

I am trying to figure out how can i make a property [NonSerialized] for a value

Check this out :

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
 
class Test
{
    public static bool GoingToBeSerialized = false;
 
 
    public int PaymentForTheDay { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
 
    // i want to disable it if GoingToBeSerialized is true
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore] 
    public int TotalPayment;
 
    public  bool ShouldSerializeTotalPayment() => GoingToBeSerialized;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK "conditional serialization" isn't available by default for `BinaryFormatter`, unless you implement `ISerializable` and do it manually; however, `BinaryFormatter` is considered deprecated and dangerous, so honestly: *you shouldn't be using it* - just about any other serializer would be better, and many would support this directly using simply `public bool ShouldSerializeTotalPayment() => GoingToBeSerialized;`

Comment: I am trying to Serialize with Json,and how can i use `public bool ShouldSerializeTotalPayment() => GoingToBeSerialized;` ??

Comment: I just want to check: are you sure you are actually using `BinaryFormatter`? I *very often* see people marking types as `[Serializable]` to use with `XmlSerializer`, `JsonConvert`, etc - where `[Serializable]` does *nothing*

Comment: @Shamilx "with JSON" - using what serializer? can you show the code you're using to serialize? it matters

Comment: I am trying to serialize with json but i am quite new to this topic :)

Comment: @Shamilx great; *how* are you trying to serialize with JSON? Please show us the line of code where you serialize - that will *probably* be enough for us to figure out which JSON serializer you are using (there are quite a few)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/b49btxiG

Comment: I changed code a little bit for you

Comment: just remove the `[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]` and you should already be set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `[Serializable]` and `[NonSerialized]` (in the original question, now removed in the edit) do *nothing* with most serializers - they only apply to `BinaryFormatter`, which you aren't using.

There's a very good chance that simply using:

```cs
public int TotalPayment {get;set;}
public bool ShouldSerializeTotalPayment() => GoingToBeSerialized;
```

will do what you want; with the recent addition of your pastebin that shows you're using Json.NET, this should indeed work - [conditional serialization is a Json.NET feature using the standard pattern](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm). Note also that I made `TotalPayment` a *property*, and removed the `[JsonIgnore]`.

Comment: Oh i am getting it now,let me try it out

Comment: So i need `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to achive this

Comment: @Shamilx oh darn it, I misread the attributes; I thought you were using Json.NET - my bad; unfortunately details matter :) System.Text.Json indeed does not support this form of conditional serialization ([it has some very primitive options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0))

Comment: I already downloaded it and worked as expected,thank you very much